# What will happen if cPanel license expires?

Tags: cpanel

Will everything still run on the server? I create and delete virtual servers a lot.

Not a big deal, but it's kind of a waste to pay cPanel $10 every time I do that.

Answer (score 3):

1. WHM / CPANEL becomes inaccessible.
2. POP/IMAP Stops working.

The web server and other services will continue to run. If you create and delete servers often then your best of learning how to use the servers without CPANEL.